# Updating custom columns on Modern Pages with SPFx WebPart vs. PowerApp

Tags: modern-pages

I created a Communications Site and under Pages, I added custom columns.  Besides letting my authors create the pages, I need a way for my authors to capture this additional information.

Out of the box, the Page Properties gives me a nice "form" that will allow my authors to enter this information, however I want to have more control on the look and feel, I want it to be part of the page and not on the side and I need to add custom validations.

Should I do this with a custom SPFx Webpart or is PowerApps an option for this.  So far, looks like PowerApps integration is more prominent with Lists, however on Pages, the PowerApp button doesn't exist.  Does that mean PowerApps is not a good candidate to manipulate data on Pages?

Curious to know what you guys are doing out there.

Thank you